# how do you translate the phrase "never stop fighting" into latin

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

My best guess would be "numquam īnsistite pūgnant". I use the plural imperative form of īnsistere, because this is technically a command from someone to "never stop fighting", and the 3rd person plural of pugnare, since this is a general message to everyone, or should it be a participle instead? What is the most appropriate way to translate this?

I want to use this as a motto for an organization based in an online game, i want the translation to be as accurate as possible, also it embarrassing for me to get this wrong since I've already taken 2 courses on latin.

Answer (score 4):

*Insistere* means “to stop” only in the sense of “to halt, to stop advancing” (i.e., to stop walking, to pause in a speech or whatever), but not in the sense of “to cease doing something.” A more fitting word would be *desinere*.

Now, a negative command would usually not use the imperative, but *ne* + perfect subjunctive. It is generally (at least in classical Latin) not done that a different negative word like *numquam* is used (although I think *nihil* is sometimes found instead of *ne quid*), so instead we would say: *Ne umquam desieritis*. And indeed, if you Google, you find this suggestion (or the singular *ne umquam desieris*) for “never stop, never give up” in a number of Latin forums.

Finally, *pugnant* means “they fight,” and I'm not really sure how you think it connects to the rest of the sentence. *Desinere* in any case usually stands with the infinitive (*pugnare desinere*), although you could also use it transitively (*pugnam desinere*). Or you could use a single-word translation for “stop fighting” like *concedere*.

So a few options would be:

- Ne umquam pugnare (*or* pugnam) desieritis.
- Ne umquam concesseritis.

Comment: Thanks I appreciate the advice

Comment: I would add form a literary point of view that you should consider whether the command should be singular or plural.  In reading the English, I first assumed this was a motto addressed to every individual in a general way and so should be in the singular.  The plural is fine, but conjures up the image of a shout on a battlefield from a soldier to their comrades or from a commander to troops: a different image.